# create a new column in sequential order with numbers representing time values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, categories, calculated-columns

I have time values and would like to create a new column with numbers representing those time values with sequential order like this:

```
date                             new_column

2019-09-17 10:50:03.999000+00:00    0
2019-09-17 10:50:03.999000+00:00    0
2019-09-17 10:50:03.999000+00:00    0
2019-09-17 10:50:04.232000+00:00    1
2019-09-17 10:50:04.232000+00:00    1
2019-09-17 10:50:04.232000+00:00    1
2019-09-17 10:50:05.208000+00:00    2
2019-09-17 10:50:05.208000+00:00    2
2019-09-17 10:50:05.208000+00:00    2
2019-09-17 10:50:06.036000+00:00    3
2019-09-17 10:50:06.036000+00:00    3
2019-09-17 10:50:06.036000+00:00    3
2019-09-17 10:50:07.250000+00:00    4
2019-09-17 10:50:07.250000+00:00    4
2019-09-17 10:50:07.250000+00:00    4
2019-09-17 10:50:08.214000+00:00    5
2019-09-17 10:50:08.214000+00:00    5
2019-09-17 10:50:08.214000+00:00    5
2019-09-17 10:50:09.206000+00:00    6
2019-09-17 10:50:09.206000+00:00    6
2019-09-17 10:50:09.206000+00:00    6
2019-09-17 10:50:10.018000+00:00    7
2019-09-17 10:50:10.018000+00:00    7
2019-09-17 10:50:10.018000+00:00    7
2019-09-17 10:50:11.264000+00:00    8 
2019-09-17 10:50:11.264000+00:00    8
2019-09-17 10:50:11.264000+00:00    8
```

I have a data set of a couple of hours, and dont want to repeat the cycle each our, but it should continue numerically until the last reading.  There must be an easy way doing this, any recommendation? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This would somewhat solve it:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sample_data = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-09-17', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-18', '2019-09-17', '2019-09-15', '2019-09-18']})

dates_unique =  pd.DataFrame({'date': sample_data.date.unique()})

dates_unique['codes'] = range(0, len(dates_unique.date))

sample_data.merge(dates_unique)

         date  codes
0  2019-09-17      0
1  2019-09-17      0
2  2019-09-15      1
3  2019-09-15      1
4  2019-09-18      2
5  2019-09-18      2
```